# Renaming a directory in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, directory, rename

I couldn't find a DirectoryInfo.Rename(To) or FileInfo.Rename(To) method anywhere.  So, I wrote my own and I'm posting it here for anybody to use if they need it, because let's face it : the MoveTo methods are overkill and will always require extra logic if you just want to rename a directory or file :

```
public static class DirectoryExtensions
{
    public static void RenameTo(this DirectoryInfo di, string name)
    {
        if (di == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("di", "Directory info to rename cannot be null");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("New name cannot be null or blank", "name");
        }

        di.MoveTo(Path.Combine(di.Parent.FullName, name));

        return; //done
    }
}
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

There is no difference between moving and renaming; you should simply call [`Directory.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx).

In general, if you're only doing a single operation, you should use the `static` methods in the `File` and `Directory` classes instead of creating `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` objects.

For more advice when working with files and directories, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278.aspx).

Comment: Pay attention that switching cases like `foo` to `Foo` will throw an IOException when done with a simple `Directory.Move` as both are regarded as the same path. So there is a difference... just saying.

Answer (score 76):

You should move it:

```
Directory.Move(source, destination);
```

Answer (score 19):

One already exists. If you cannot get over the "Move" syntax of the `System.IO` namespace. There is a static class `FileSystem` within the **Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO** namespace that has both a `RenameDirectory` and `RenameFile` already within it.

As mentioned by SLaks, this is just a wrapper for `Directory.Move` and `File.Move`.

Comment: All they do is validate parameters and call `Directory.Move` and `File.Move`.  I checked.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I think his complaint is because "Move" does not make you automatically think "Rename." If he wants the Syntax, it exists in that format, just in another namespace.

Comment: Move means rename for any unix user :)