# I am trying to get the input of a javascript textbox saved back to server. I want to get the input from the pop up textbox saved to rename a folder.

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to pass the value of a javascript textbox to the server using an asp.net hidden field. Not sure what to do in code behind to save submitted value.

```
$(function () {
$(":asp(btnCopy)").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("<div></div>").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Do you want to rename this folder?",
        height: 100,
        width: 300,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                var name = window.prompt("Please enter new folder name", "");
                function getNewFolderName() {
                    var newFolderName = 'name';
                    document.getElementById('<%=newFolderName.ClientID%>').value = "";
                }
                __doPostBack($(":asp(btnCopy)").prop('name'));
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                alert("Folder saved without rename");
                __doPostBack($(":asp(btnCopy)").prop('name'));
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnCopy"  runat="server" SkinID="Copy" ToolTip="Click to copy folder."
                        OnClick="btnCopy_Click" Enabled="false"  />&nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" ToolTip="Click to go to Library home."
                        SkinID="Cancel" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="newFolderName" runat="server" Value="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how i finally got this to work. jQuery referenced the hidden field and i called it in code behind to pass the value. Thanks Alot to User AhmedGadir for all his help.

```
    $(function () {
$(":asp(btnCopy)").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("<div></div>").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Do you want to rename this folder?",
        height: 100,
        width: 300,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                var name = window.prompt("Please enter new folder name", "");
                $(":asp(newFolderName)").prop('value', name);
                __doPostBack($(":asp(btnCopy)").prop('name'));

            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                alert("Folder saved without rename");
                __doPostBack($(":asp(btnCopy)").prop('name'));
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});

```
    string folderName = newFolderName.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code behind (C#) code (it should be the .CS class that matches your page name) create (if not already exist) a function handling the click event "btnCopy_Click"  There you can put your code to update the folder creation. Use the IO library to do that... I will look for an example for you

Comment: Look at this For IO (folder changing code) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023975/renaming-a-directory-in-c-sharp

Comment: Try this
  $(this).dialog('close');
                var name = window.prompt("Please enter new folder name", "");
                function getNewFolderName() {
                    var newFolderName = 'name';
                    document.getElementById('<%=newFolderName.ClientID%>').value = newFolderName;
                }